# When persisting user state with a KendoUI grid using the Asp.Net MVC HtmlHelper, the grid hangs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've used this code as the template for preserving grid state:
http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/web/grid/preserve-grid-state-in-a-cookie.aspx

This works as long as I persist everything but the grouping.  Once I enable persisting of the grouping, I get this error from the Kendo javascript: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Here is the grid using the HtmlHelper:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<VideoSummaryModel>()
.Name("VideosGrid")
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(v => v.Topics).Title("Topic");
    columns.Bound(v => v.Title)
    columns.Bound(v => v.LastUpdated).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
    columns.Bound(v => v.InstructorName)
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Filterable()                    
.Groupable(grouping=>grouping.Enabled(!HasInstructorFilter))
.Events(evt => {
    evt.DataBound("persistLibraryGrid");
})
.DataSource(ds => ds
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(25)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Videos", new { searchString = ViewBag.SearchString }))
    ))
```

Here is the code to persist the state in a cookie:

```
//kendo grid
function persistGridSettings(grid, pageName) {

    if (grid && grid.dataSource){
    var dataSource = grid.dataSource;

    group = dataSource.group();

    var state = kendo.stringify({
        page: dataSource.page(),
        pageSize: dataSource.pageSize(),
        sort: dataSource.sort(),
        //There is a bug in the programmatic interaction with the grouping collection
        group: dataSource.group(),
        filter: dataSource.filter()
    });

setCookie(getGridCookieName(pageName), state);
}
}
```

Here is the code to load cookie back into the grid state:

```
function getGridSettings(grid, pageName) {
    if (grid && grid.dataSource) {
        var state = JSON.parse(getCookie(getGridCookieName(pageName)));
        if (state) {
            if (state.filter) {
                parseFilterDates(state.filter, grid.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields);
            }
            grid.dataSource.query(state);
        }
        else {
            grid.dataSource.read();
        }
    }
}
```

Jeremy

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: No, I believe we moved to the next update of the kendo toolkit and it was resovled.

Comment: @JeremySchrader I have the same problem too but when i update my kendo js version its resolved sometimes kendo versions has bug or some marketing strategies to sell new updates like this